# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in C when Implementing list ADT

Tags: c, list, runtime-error

I'm trying to implement a list ADT in C but I keep getting the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I know it is caused by accessing memory that cannot be used, but I have no idea how to fix it (I am very new to data structures so sorry if there's an obvious error)

Here's the list.h file:

```
typedef struct node NodeType;

struct node {
  int num;
  NodeType *next;
};

typedef struct {
  int length;
  NodeType *head;
} List;

void init(int maxSize, List *L);
void print(List L);
```

and this is the list.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"
void init(int maxSize, List *L) {
   (*L).length = maxSize;
   (*L).head=NULL;
}

void print(List L) {
 int i; 
 NodeType *p;

 printf("List is: ");
 for (i=0, p=L.head; i<L.length; i++, p=(*p).next) {
   printf(" %d ", (*p).num);
 }
 putchar('\n');
}
```

and this is the main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"


int main(void){
  List L;
  init(10, &L);
  //add(&L, 20); add(&L, 41); add(&L, 63);
  print(L);
  return 0;
}
```

what should I do? which part is exactly wrong?

Comment: Quick style note:  `(*L).length` is equivalent to `L->length`.

Comment: Using `->` become much, much cleaner when you compare `(*((*a).b))).c` to `a->b->c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked lists do not traditionally track their length. Length rather is calculated by iterating until we hit a null pointer.

In your code, your `init` function sets the length of the list to `10`. Then in `print`, you use this value to iterate 10 times, despite the fact that there are only 3 elements in your list. This is causing your segmentation fault.

You can add a check to `print` to avoid this:

```
 for (i=0, p=L.head; i<L.length && p != NULL; i++, p=(*p).next) {
   printf(" %d ", (*p).num);
 }
```

But I think you really need to rethink why you're initializing length to `10` at all, and why you're tracking the length of a list this way at all.

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much! (btw I'm tracking the length of list because later on in the assignment it will be used a lot and I don't want to calculate it every time)

Comment: You could have your `add` function return an `int` that indicates the length of the list. Then you can store that and not have to recalculate length.

Comment: That sounds good, I'll try to do that instead. Thank you so much again! If you don't mind me asking this, do you know any good tutorials for data structures? I'm a bit struggling in class and in your profile you say that you are self-taught so I thought you should know)

Comment: Yes, but that was a _long_ time ago in a galaxy far, far away. These days I'd search for a good university class that provides materials for its class freely online. If you were working in OCaml I'd suggest Cornell's CS3110 notes.